# ChoiceBox option changes layout in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

How to adjust (extend) layout according to ChoiceBox selected option? My main window consists of ChoiceBox (with several options) and Exit button. When a user expands the list and chooses one option, layout should change in such a way, that ChoiceBox (with selected item) is preserved but depending on selection a few forms and labels are added to create a kind of fill form. My idea is as follows:

```
choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Number value, Number new_value) {
                try {
                    stage = (Stage) choiceBox.getScene().getWindow();
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                    choiceBox.getSelectionModel().select(new_value.intValue());
                    Parent parent = loader.load(getClass().getResource(Strings.addItemLayouts[new_value.intValue()]).openStream());
                    Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Where `addItemLayouts` is a string array which consists of paths to new layouts according to selected item.
Each layout has it's controller defined to be the same as the main window controller. Is it good approach or is it possible to do it in a better way?

Comment: You already have a solution, what exactly is your question?  Is there something wrong with the solution you have in your question?

Comment: Where is the "keeping the `ChoiceBox`" part in your code? It replaces the whole scene containing the `ChoiceBox` with the content from the fxml. If you want to change only parts of the scene, you need to design the scene in a way that modifying one layout will show the new content but keep the `ChoiceBox`. Also you could possibly cache the content from the fxmls to avoid reloading it... `choiceBox.getSelectionModel().select(new_value.intValue());` seems pretty unnecessary btw: You're reacting to such a change, no need to select the same item selected by user interaction again from your code.

Comment: How can i keep the state of ChoiceBox? And what if I have like 15 controlls divided into 5 different categories (which can be chosen using ChoiceBox) - should I store code for this controllers in one file or should I make 5 different files?